# html5 video doesn't load on chrome iPad

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, html5-video

For some reasons, the html5 video doesn't play on chrome on iPad but plays well on safari iPad. Any ideas why? It works on chrome on Mac/PC.

```
<video id="homepage_videoplayer" 
  poster="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.png" 
  preload="auto" loop="loop"  autoplay="autoplay" width="979" height="365">

    <source src="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://actisku.videohosting.fr/medias/videos/v_actisku_visualproject_sephora_61.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />

</video>
```

Link: http://actisku.videohosting.fr/test_integration2.html